# How would I place my logo on top of the space background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layer

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbdaVB

```
Check the codepen.io for code. Sorry, new to Stack Overflow, please don't hurt me if I'm doing it wrong. ;-;
```

I have my logo (https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0nWc.png) in the code already, but can someone make it so that my logo is in front of the space background?

Thanks.
Miles.

Comment: can't understand your question.

Comment: In the codepen, there is a space background. I want it so that my logo is on top of the moving space background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First target the image tag with the `class="logo"`, also you need use double quotes(`""`) in the src, not `¨¨`.

```
<img  class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/CIwEPgT.png">
```

Them, in your CSS, add this:

```
.logo {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxRmWO

Comment: did you change the image src? because here is working.

Comment: If you fix it, fork it and send it. :)

Comment: I love you. And I'll love you forever.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `z-index` of the image to be a higher number and positioning it on top of the background? Also, I'd advise not using center tags.

Comment: Yes. @MrBearAndBeer helped me with it. But thanks for the tip!